# CountDownTimer in Kotlin explanation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, countdowntimer

I am very very new to Kotlin and as well as Java.
I have search around the web and found tutorials about using CountDownTimer in Kotlin but i still do not understand. I am trying to create an android app with a page that whenever you open it, it counts down for 60 sec to 0.

Below is what I have done, Was trying to create a charade game.
The problem is that there is an error on textTimer.text, (unresolved reference), i don't see where i am wrong though. And is my Timer correct? Is there a better and easier way to do it?

I follow this tutorial. https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/04/android-kotlin-countdowntimer-days.html

```
package com.example.sim.charades
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class QuickStart : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_start)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val textTimer = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textTimer)
        val arrayTerms = arrayListOf("Burger", "Pie", "Fries", "Donuts", "Chocolates", "Sweets")

        val rand = Random().nextInt(arrayTerms.count())
        textView.text = arrayTerms[rand]

        // 60 seconds (1 minute)
        val minute:Long = 60000

        // 1 day 2 hours 35 minutes 50 seconds
        val millisInFuture:Long = (minute * 1440) + (minute * 155) + (1000 * 50)

        // Count down interval 1 second
        val countDownInterval:Long = 1000

        timer(millisInFuture,countDownInterval).start()


    }

    private fun timer(millisInFuture:Long,countDownInterval:Long):CountDownTimer{
        return object: CountDownTimer(millisInFuture,countDownInterval){
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long){
                val timeRemaining = timeString(millisUntilFinished)
                textTimer.text = timeRemaining
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                //nothing Yet
            }
        }
    }

    private fun timeString(millisUntilFinished:Long):String{
        var millisUntilFinished:Long = millisUntilFinished

        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)

        // Format the string
        return String.format(
                Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d sec",
                seconds
        )
    }


}
```

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not yet inflated in the `onCreate` method.
Move your view initialization into the `onViewCreated` method and you should be able to resolve your TextView reference.

Also, using `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` you don't have to use `findViewById`, you can directly access your view by its `id`. You can remove those lines (your variables seem to match the id name)

Comment: Ahh thanks for the tips man. I just move down val textTimer = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textTimer) and it works. But how do you access it with just id?

Comment: You don't have to keep affectations. Just remove `val textTimer = findViewById....` and directly call textTimer.text = arrayTerms[rand] . As long as you have to kotlinx import with the right layout path, you're all good. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if your problem is solved ;)